# IONIC3 push notification not working in IOS DEVICE

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, push-notification

I do not know what else to do ... i watch tutorials, I read documentation, and no results so far ... I really need help, who can at least look at my code to find out what's wrong .. I needed it a lot use this

**CONFIG.XML**

```
  <platform name="ios">
        <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.2.3">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="931157632289" />
    </plugin>
```

**App.componet.ts**

```
   platform.ready().then(() => {

      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
      alert('TESTE1');
      this.push.hasPermission()
      .then((res: any) => {
        if (res.isEnabled) {
          alert('We have permission to send push notifications');



        } else {
          alert('We do not have permission to send push notifications');
          const options: PushOptions = {
            android: {},
            ios: {
              alert: 'true',
              badge: true,
              sound: 'false'
            },
            windows: {},
            browser: {
              pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
            }
          };

          const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);


          pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
            alert(notification.message);
          });

          pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) =>{
            alert( registration);
          });

          pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error =>{ 
            alert(error);
          });

        }

      });



    });
```

IMAGE 1:[Image of my APNS certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im70t.png)

IMAGE 2: [Cloud Messaging Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMBdp.png)

IMAGE 3: [Screenshot of my smartphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdHZL.jpg)

Comment: Have you uploaded the APNS dev and prod certs to Firebase console ?

Comment: I had not done it yet, but I did now, and still the message does not arrive ... https://imgur.com/a/EyXJa5u

Comment: Since you are trying Ionic, I would suggest you a better plugin for Push notifications 
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fcm/  - Which I'm using it in my recent app.

Comment: FIRMessaging received data-message, but FIRMessagingDelegate's-messaging:didReceiveMessage: not implemented